# Class property with optional parameter?

Tags: python, properties

Is it possible to define a class property that optionally accepts parameters?

Something like:

```
class Class:
    @property
    def my_number(self, n=0):
        return 1 + n

c = Class()
c.my_number
>> 1
c.my_number(1)
>> 2
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. Use a regular method when you want to pass a parameter.

Comment: But it should be possible with an adequate decorator, right?

Comment: `c.my_number` would need to return an object that is both a value in itself, *and* callable. That’s possible with a custom class which implements a ton of magic methods, but is probably too complicated to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> No, it's not possible. Use a regular method when you want to pass a parameter.

> `c.my_number` would need to return an object that is both a value in itself, and callable. That’s possible with a custom class which implements a ton of magic methods, but is probably too complicated to make sense.

Fully agree with these comments. I have tried to implement the ton of magic methods and didn't get anywhere!